# JQuery trigger not working as expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, triggers, document-ready

I would like to `trigger` `button` on **document.ready()** and do  **ajax call** event on that triggered button event.

This is what I mean to say:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#btnLoad").trigger("click");


    $("#btnLoad").click(function () {

         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Default.aspx/GetDetails",
         data: "{}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) {
         }
        });//ajax

      });//btnClick

  });//JQuery
```

Now my problem is I'm unable to trigger that button.

If I give a normal alert in the place of btn trigger it's working fine.
Can anyone point out what the mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your trigger is called before bind, move the trigger after binding click handler.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {    

    $("#btnLoad").click(function () {

         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Default.aspx/GetDetails",
         data: "{}",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) {
         }
        });//ajax

      }).click();//btnClick <-- Trigger click

  });//JQuery
```

**Note:** I have used `.click()` to trigger click handler.